# Как в javascript реализовать функционал генерации и обработки событий на уровне класса?

Tags: javascript

Как в javascript реализовать функционал генерации и обработки событий на уровне класса?

Ниже приведенный код не работает. Как его подправить чтобы он заработал?

```
class MyClass {
    func(){
        this.dispatch("Done");
    }

    addEventListener(){

    }

    dispatch(){
        
    }

}

var m = new MyClass();
m.addEventListener("Done", function(){
    console.log("Done");
});
m.func();
```

Comment: очевидно в класс нужно добавить метод `addEventListener` и метод `dispatch`

Comment: Пожалуйста, помогите модифицировать код до рабочего состояния. Я могу добавить два этих метода, но мне не понятно, что в методах самих прописывать.

Comment: в addEventListener достаточно сохранять обработчики, а в dispatch - нужно просто пробежаться по сохраненным обработчикам и вызвать их

Comment: Это консольное приложение будет. Не понимаю 1 и 2 пункт.

Comment: заведи в классе поле, объект, в котором ключом будет имя события, а значением массив, в который ты будешь добавлять обработчики.

Comment: Ссылку можете дать на какой-то обучающий пример. Приблизительно понимаю о чем речь, но хочу на примере разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подчерпнул отсюда: [stackoverflow.com/a/53917410/8628377](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53917410/8628377)

Создал две функции, первая, с помощью `CustomEvent` подставляет какие-то данные в объект `Event.detail`. Вторая функция просто делает оповещение, без каких-либо данных.

```js
class MyClass extends EventTarget {
    func(){
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('Done', { detail: [1, 2, 3] }));
    }
    eventWithoutDetail(){
        this.dispatchEvent(new Event('Done'));
    }
}

const myClass = new MyClass();

myClass.addEventListener('Done', (e) => {
    console.log('Done from event...', e.detail || null);
});

myClass.eventWithoutDetail();
setTimeout(() => {
    myClass.func();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: А в консольном приложении будет работать?)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, а почему бы и нет? :-) Если есть EventTarget - значит будет :)

Comment: @Grundy А разве в nodejs есть `EventTarget`? Ждем следующего вопроса, почему не работает  `EventTarget` от ТС :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, не, там по другому называется. Но еще неизвестно нужно ли это для nodejs :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko в `nodejs` есть модуль `events`, куда удобнее чем данные вариант.